# Calculating fully connected mesh topology network count in Java

Tags: java, recursion

The question is to calculate the connection count of a fully connected mesh topology network. The total number of connections can be calculated with the formula (n x (n-1)) / 2. We are to implement the public class `ConnectionCount` method recursively and everything else was given to us. The problem is that it compiles but does not run correctly. Each `connectionCount` returns a value of 0. Please help, this is what I have so far:

```
public class ConnectionCount {

    public int ConnectionCalc(int n) {
        if (n > 0) {
            return(n-1) + ConnectionCalc(n-1);
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }   

    public static int connectionCount(int n) {
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println("connectionCount(" + i + ") returns " + connectionCount(i));

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What else do you expect if the method body contains only `return 0;` ? Note that `ConnectionCalc` is called nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the method `connectionCount` that returns 0 always instead of calling `ConnectionCalc` method. You will have to declare `ConnectionCalc` as static too.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was an oversight on my part